# PHP - redirect page with header after database updated

Tags: php, pdo, header

i trying to update my database field when form submitted , and then redirect to a page with header function , but page can't redirect and stay . what's the problem ?

```
session_start();
include("database.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    // custom function
    $connect = connectToDatabase();
    $database = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET address = :address , message = :message WHERE id = :id ");
    $database->bindParam(":address", $address);
    $database->bindParam(":message", $message);
    $database->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $success = $database -> execute() ;
        if($success){
            header("location:../panel/");
            exit;
        }
 }else{
   header("location:../panel/");
   exit;
}
```

Comment: `but page can't redirect and stay` <-- that's a contradiction. You need to do a better job of explaining what your problem is.

Comment: make it clear bro :) we are here to help

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can proceed and see, what works :

1> In your form element add data-ajax=false.( This fixes the issue with jquery mobile)

2> Instead of relative URI use absolute URI as argument.